# MDF file size and performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have peaks where latency (as measured by [Physical Disk\Avg Disk Sec read] on the drive where our data file is) goes up to 0.2 sec.

I immediately started suspecting the SAN while the DBA is suspecting that this is related to the fact that we currently have a single MDF file that is 5 terabytes.

Does a very large MDF file negatively impact latency? If so what is the appropriate size?

I have not seen a lot of content on this subject.

Thanks!
-Xavier

Comment: Did you check for auto-growth events? If you have a 5 TB file and you have auto-growth set to 1 MB or 10% then yeah, data changes could be a real problem.

Comment: Also, check that Instant file initialization is enabled so that the autogrowth event can leverage it when an MDF needs to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a very large MDF file negatively impact latency? If so what is the appropriate size?

Only the size of MDF **does not impact IO latency**. Latency is related to your disk IO subsystem, its configuration and [disk partition alignment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmymay/archive/2014/03/14/disk-partition-alignment-for-windows-server-2012-sql-server-2012-and-sql-server-2014.aspx).

To find out if disk subsystem is a bottleneck, use [`sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/) DMV or [Capturing IO latencies for a period of time](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-io-latencies-period-time/)

Having [multiple data files on separate LUNs *- depends on number of CPU Cores*](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/benchmarking-do-multiple-data-files-make-a-difference/) will help to alleviate contention to some extent as well.

Look at the NUMA configuration of your server instance, since [there is a single I/O thread and a single lazy writer thread for each NUMA node.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/02/how-it-works-soft-numa-i-o-completion-thread-lazy-writer-workers-and-memory-nodes.aspx).

> We have peaks where latency (as measured by [Physical Disk\Avg Disk Sec read] on the drive where our data file is) goes up to 0.2 sec.

You should look into the autogrowth events and if there are frequent autogrowth events fired, you will see a performance hit. Make sure, [you have configured autogorowth to a reasonable value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46686/8783) - definitely away from Percent increase. Also, configure [Instant file initialization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46686/8783), so that data files can leverage its awesomeness.